# Regular expression that identifies all instances of a string based on multiple leading character types and trailing characters in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to find a way to identify all cases within a single variable that meet the following criteria:

- Leading character is a numeric value [0:9] **OR** the letter "T" or "L", **AND**:
- Trailing characters are numeric values that are 2 to 4 digits long

Below, my "input" dataframe is what I have, and my "output" dataframe is what I want:

```
input <- c("T26", "023", "X579", "17432", "L8762", "T665778", "487295", "7843")
output <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

I figure that constructing a regular expression is the best way to accomplish this (correct me if I'm wrong), but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own through trial and error, nor have I found any stackoverflow questions that meet my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is 487295 FALSE or T665778 FALSE.

Comment: 487295 is FALSE because the "4" is followed by more than 4 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to match the digits or letters T, L (`[0-9TL]`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by digits 2 to 4 (`\\d{2,4}`) till the end (`$`) of the string

```
grepl('^[0-9TL]\\d{2,4}$', input)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Tried to, but you were too quick. I have to wait a couple more minutes before I can accept! And for those who downvoted, what exactly was wrong with my question? It was clearly written and included a simple reproducible example.

Comment: @mkpcr - I didn't downvote, but it's not absolutely clear. Does "leading characters" mean one character? Multiple characters?